# How to switch Intellij Idea project vcs between Gitlab and Amazon CodeCommit?

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control, gitlab, aws-codecommit

I am new with Amazon codecommit.

Following their instruction, I did some works like below

- make a new IAM user with AdministratorAccess
- make a new codecommit repository
- install `awscli` and did `aws configure`

When I right finished those things, I could pull/push from codecommit.
However it became disabled with intellij Idea.

I did something like...

- I pull a project from gitlab
- `git remote rm origin`
- `git remote add origin [code commit url]`
- `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master`

Now I type `git [pull / push] origin master`, I got this error message.

```
unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/test17/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

When I access this url via browser, it requires id/pw. But my IAM user account information is not working.

What should I do? Is there any way to switch gitlab and codecommit in intellij?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ does not use awscli. It uses the default system shell.

From the description, it looks like push/pull does not work for the command-line git in the native shell, so the issue is not IntelliJ-related.

Probably git tries to use wrong credentials save in its credential.helper, that is why it fails.

Check `git config credential.helper` to see if any is configured. If there is one, try disabling it or clear the saved credentials.

Answer (score 0):

From the description it looks like you are trying to connect to a CodeCommit repository in Intellij using https.  To do this you need to generate GitCredentials(username/password) for your iam user in the IAM console.
Detailed steps are documented in the aws documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html

Once you have the username/password you can use those credentials to connect to your CodeCommit repository in Intellij.

Answer (score 0):

**Tested on a Mac. Your milage may vary!**

I just ran into the same issue.  MacOS stores the GIT UID and PW in the Keychain (in your Applications > Utilities Folder).  I deleted all references to AWS Code Commit from the keychain, which forced me to reenter the UID & PW. This seems to have solve the problem.

**As a side note:**  I think this happened because I revoked a prior GIT credential on AWS and created a new one.  I think that the keychain was entering the old UID/PW which then failed during authentication.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are going to want to create an IAM user with appropriate permissions and then create Git credentials. Then go to IntelliJ IDEA and say you are opening project from VCS with Git credentials, use the AWS git credentials you created and log in. Once you have logged in, you should be able to pull/push to the repo. If you are still having issues and have checked the credentials you are using are active, along with the IAM user those credentials are attached to have the right permissions, I would recommend creating a ticket on AWS support as there may be something wrong with your account that AWS staff will need to fix.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.